# clang and gcc linters checks syntax wrong

Tags: vim-plugin, syntax-checking

I use [ALE](https://github.com/w0rp/ale) vim plugin which lints with clang and gcc by default. If I write program on C and define variable of `ssize_t` type ALE will marks it as mistake with message "unknown type name 'ssize_t'; did you mean 'size_t'?", regardless of `ssize_t` is defined in stdio.h and program is compiled successfully by gcc. I suppose that gcc and clang linters doesn't follow stdio.h and need to be configured. Probably I should set `g:ale_c_clang_options` and `g:ale_gcc_options` variables in vim. I have tried

`let g:ale_c_clang_options = '-std=c11 -Wall -I/usr/include'
let g:ale_linters = {'c': ['clang']}`

Result is the same.

UPD:
I have changed linters dictionary in .vimrc and error message disappears.

`let g:ale_linters = {'c': ['clangtidy']}`

But I still don't know how to configure clang and gcc linters proper way.